# How to fill the window height and width in vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am having a hard time as to how do i make a layout/container in vuetify fill the entire screen's height and width. Please give an example on how to do this. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fluid` to get the full width of viewport, and `fill-height` to get the full height of the viewport. `fluid` is a prop, `fill-height` is a class.

```
<v-container fluid class="primary fill-height">
  <v-row>
    <v-col>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```